# Permanently Leave Navigation Controller in Xcode

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller

The starting point for my app is a simple login screen. If the user wants to make a new account, then they will segue into a navigation controller which manages all the views for creating a new account. The problem is that after they have made the account and signed in, the navigation bar is still there (pressing the back button will bring them to the "enter a password" page). I don't want to simply *hide* the navigation bar, I want the navigation controller and it's whole stack of views to be gone completely.

Comment: Putting your new ViewController in another NavigationController should solve it.

Comment: One way would be to set the `window.rootViewController` in your `AppDelegate` to a different view controller.

Answer (score 1):

First of all after a successfull registration don't wait the user to click back or any thing automatically direct it to the main content VC of the app by changing the root of the AppDelegate's window to the mainVC embeded in a navigation controller , so later you can push other VCs to it like user settings , about VCs and so on

first create a new nav

```
let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
let viewController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier :"mainView") as! mainViewController
let navController = UINavigationController.init(rootViewController: viewController)
```

and assign it to root

```
  let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate
  appDelegate?.window?.rootViewController = navController
```

Answer (score 0):

You can Remove login screen from navigation controller using below code:

```
override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillDisappear(animated)
        var tempVCs = self.navigationController?.viewControllers
        for tempVC: UIViewController in tempVCs {
        // remove login screen from navigation stack
        if (tempVC is LoginScreenVC) {
            tempVC.removeFromParentViewController()
        }
    }
    }
```